# What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?

Tags: html, xhtml

What's the difference between `<b>` and `<strong>`, `<i>` and `<em>` in HTML/XHTML? When should you use each?

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/255588/12693

Comment: At least for now, everything I saw in StackOverflow was "bolded" using <b> element

Comment: MDN has clear description (with examples) on how these tags should be used: [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em), [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong), [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b), [`<i>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)

Comment: A screen reader will pronounce the words in <em> with an emphasis, using verbal stress.

Answer (score 1195, accepted):

They have the **same effect on normal web browser rendering engines**, but there is a **fundamental difference** between them.

As the author writes in [a discussion list post](https://web.archive.org/web/20091124170143/http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20010521/032901.html):

Think of three different situations:

- web browsers
- blind people
- mobile phones

"Bold" is a style - when you say *"bold a word"*, people basically know that 
it means to add more, let's say "ink", around the letters until they stand out 
more amongst the rest of the letters.

That, unfortunately, means nothing to a blind person. On mobile phones
and other PDAs, text is already bold because screen resolution is very small. You can't bold a bold without screwing something up.

**`<b>` is a style** - we know what "bold" is supposed to look like.

**`<strong>`** however **is an indication of how something should be understood**. "Strong" could (and often does) mean "bold" in a browser, but it could also mean a lower tone for a speaking program like Jaws (for blind people) or be represented by an underline (since you can't bold a bold) on a Palm Pilot.

HTML was never meant to be about styles. Do [some searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Tim+Berners+Lee%22+%22Semantic+Web%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a) for [*"Tim Berners-Lee"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) and *"the semantic web."* `<strong>` is semantic—it describes the text it surrounds (e.g., *"this text should be stronger than the rest of the text you've displayed"*) as opposed to describing *how* the text it surrounds *should be displayed* (e.g., *"this text should be bold"*).

Comment: Note that <b> and <i> have **not** been deprecated in HTML5. Their new use is to semantically represent styles (or intended presentation), whereas <strong> and <em> represent **structure**. You must read http://stellify.net/html5-b-and-i-tags-are-going-to-be-useful-read-semantic-again/

Comment: Great answer but I would say that "you can't bold a bold" is wrong because you're assuming it's a boolean concept, when font-weight: takes a more variable approach.  Now that high fidelity screens exists, there are levels of boldness.

Comment: @TravisO I believe he was speaking to the specific technical restrictions of the Palm Pilot.

Comment: I don't believe bunch of letters have any intrinsic meaning, <b> can have exactly the same semantic meaning as <strong> if we decide so. What did makers of readers decided, do they treat them differently or exactly in the same way?

Comment: @deathApril But they do! They do have meaning! HTML is not defined by what you believe or what you decide.

Comment: Your discussion list post link is dead. Have another resource?

Comment: Informative answer, but if I got it right, the only practical difference is when it comes to text-to-speech software? In spite of that, it seems futile to me to have more than one tag for something like bolding. When someone visits a web site, (s)he won't see which tag is used, hence, there is no difference.

Comment: @TravisO font-weight is CSS.

Comment: @poepje: If presentation were all that mattered and semantics were not a concern, then yes, there wouldn't be much of a difference.

Comment: @poepje ....but semantics should ALWAYS be a concern. You never know when you'll want to re-purpose or adapt something like a webpage for a more general purpose. Since certain style-sheet/markup technologies *do* treat the `<b>` and `<strong>` tags differently, you have no guarantee that there will never be a difference, *even if* you don't initially *plan* for the markup to be seen by different technologies. (Especially in the case of the web, where you have absolutely no way of knowing how people will use your content.)

Comment: This [programmers.se] [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/255588/6402) now nicely summarises the situation too.

Comment: I like the example: a lower tone for a speaking program like Jaws (for blind people).

Comment: *Under HTML5* (and 7 years later), I disagree with '<b> is a style - we know what "bold" is supposed to look like' - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1348704/2864740. The HTML 5 LD also explicitly calls out  "Style sheets can be used to format b elements, just like any other element can be restyled. Thus, it is not the case that content in b elements will necessarily be boldened."

Comment: @splattne: "<strong> however is an indication of how something should be understood. "Strong" could (and often does) mean "bold" in a browser, but it could also mean a lower tone for a speaking program like Jaws (for blind people). And strong on a Palm Pilot may be an underline (since you can't bold a bold)." Is this the same for `<Em>`? Is `<Em>` typically rendered as italic yet with the same semantic potential for other renderings in certain restricted contexts?

Comment: Please do not use idiom when giving answer. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 285):

`<b>` and `<i>` are explicit - they specify bold and italic respectively.

`<strong>` and `<em>` are semantic - they specify that the enclosed text should be "strong" or "emphasised" in some way, usually bold and italic, but allow for the actual styling to be controlled via CSS.  Hence these are preferred in modern web pages.

Comment: Good explanation. On the other hand, with HTML 5, <i> and <b> are semantic rather than explicit as well. Sigh.

Comment: Yes, the best explanation I've read is http://stellify.net/html5-b-and-i-tags-are-going-to-be-useful-read-semantic-again/

Comment: [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html) has new semantic meanings for `b` and `i`. They are tags you should use when you need to draw attention to a part of prose, or to offset normal prose, *without* conveying emphasis (`em`), importance (for `strong`), or relevance (for `mark`). `b` is for key words, product names, actionable words, etc., while `i` is for technical terms, thoughts, phrases, etc. Honestly IMO, there needs to be a greater distinction between the two.

Comment: Too bad the stellify.net text (and title) is completely unreadable on most cheap office monitors and setups ^^ (the lack of contrast is simply stunning)

Comment: So `<b>` once really used to set the style?

Answer (score 32):

`<strong>` and `<em>` add extra semantic meaning to your document. It just so happens that they also give a bold and italic style to your text.

You could of course override their styling with CSS.

`<b>` and `<i>` on the other hand only apply font styling and should no longer be used. (Because you're supposed to format with CSS, and if the text was actually important then you would probably make it "strong" or "emphasised" anyway!)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: if you say, <b> and <i> should no longer be used, then what about old browser which doesn't support <em> and <strong>?

Comment: @Nirman If someone uses an old browser to navigate the web, he or she has many problems already, from a visual and security point of view. Because of that, I believe that programmers and designers should not support old browsers anymore.

Comment: Note: if we say old browsers, we mean Netscape 3 and IE2 here (IE3 and NS4 already supported <strong> and <em>). If you really need to keep supporting those 20th century browsers, you are in really big troubles.

Comment: `<b> and <i> on the other hand only apply font styling and should no longer be used.` Official HTML5 docs say otherwise. Citation needed?

Comment: This answer was posted ~6 years before HTML5 was released!

Comment: @James that doesn't mean you can't either a) update it with new information, b) edit  it to highlight which standard/version does it relate to, with a note that it's outdated.

Answer (score 14):

I'm going to hazard a historical and practical hot take here:

Yes, according to specifications, `<strong>` had a semantic meaning in HTML4 and `<b>` had a strictly presentational meaning.

Yes, when HTML5 came along, new semantic meaning that was slightly different was introduced for `b` and `i`.

Yes, the [W3C recommends](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags.en) — basically — TL,DR; don't use b and i.

> You should always bear in mind that the content of a b element may not always be bold, and that of an i element may not always be italic. The actual style is dependent on the CSS style definitions. You should also bear in mind that bold and italic may not be the preferred style for content in certain languages. You should not use b and i tags if there is a more descriptive and relevant tag available.

BUT:

The real world internet has massive loads of existing HTML that is never going to get updated. The real world internet has to account for content generated and copy and pasted between a vast network of software and CMS systems that all have different developer teams and were built in different eras.

So if you're writing HTML or building a system that writes HTML for other people — sure — definitely use `<strong>` instead of `<b>` to mean "strongly emphasized" because it's more semantically correct.

But really, the on-the-ground reality is that the semantic and stylistic meaning of `<strong>` and `<b>` have merged over time out of necessity.

If I'm building a CMS that allows any pasting of styled text, I need to plan both for people who are pasting in `<b>` and mean "strongly emphasized" and for people who are pasting in `<strong>` and mean "make this text bold". It might not be "right", but it's how the real world works at this moment in time.

And so, if I'm writing a stylesheet for that site, I'm probably going to end up writing some styles that look like this:

```
b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
  /* ... more styles here */
}

i,
em {
  font-style: italic;
  /* ... more styles here */
}
```

Or, I'm going to rely on the browser defaults, which do the same thing as the code above in every modern browser I know of.

Or, I might be one of probably millions of sites that use [normalize.css, which takes care to ensure that b and strong are treated the same](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/fc091cce1534909334c1911709a39c22d406977b/normalize.css#L95).

There's such a massive ocean of HTML out there in the world already that works off of this expectation, I just can't imagine that `b` will EVER be depreciated in favor of `strong` or that browsers will ever start displaying them differently by default.

So that's it. That's my hot take on semantics, history and the real world. Are b/i and strong/em the same? No. Will they probably both exist and be treated as identical in almost every situation until the collapse of modern civilization? I think, yes.

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answer. Just because few hipsters want to go back in time and change the meaning of the bold tag doesn't suddenly mean it changes. The people who wish to change history also forget that bold is actually an adjective! It literally means bold as in fearless or strongly. It is both semantic and implies a style. The movement of webdevs to make things harder for job security is no reason to force everyone to start typing more. If anything strong is redundant an unnecessarily verbose. It also doesn't align with our long history of print. Don't kill history for job security.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a summary of definitions together with suggested usage:

`<b>` ...a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as **key words** in a document abstract, **product names** in a review, **actionable words** in interactive text-driven software, or an **article lede**.

`<strong>` ...now represents importance rather than strong emphasis.

`<i>` ...a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a *taxonomic designation*, a *technical term*, an *idiomatic phrase from another language*, a *thought*, or a *ship name* in Western texts.

`<em>` ...indicates emphasis.

(These are all direct quotes from W3C sources, with my emphasis added. See: https://rawgithub.com/whatwg/html-differences/master/Overview.html#changed-elements and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1 for the originals)

Answer (score 7):

`<b>` and `<i>` are both related to style, whereas `<em>` and `<strong>` are semantic. In HTML 4, the first are classified as [font style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1), and the latter as [phrase elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1).

As you indicated correctly, `<i>` and `<em>` are often considered similar, because browsers often render both in italics. But according to the specifications, `<em>` *indicates emphasis* and `<strong>` *indicates stronger emphasis*, which is quite clear, but often misinterpreted. On the other hand, the distinction between when to use `<i>` or `<b>` is really a matter of style.

Comment: `strong` does not indicate "stronger emphasis" but rather "[importance](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-strong-element.html#the-strong-element)." For [stronger emphasis](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-em-element.html#the-em-element), nest an `em` element inside another `em` element.

Comment: @TestSubject528491 if you follow the link for [phrase elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1) I have used above, you will see that I have just quoted the spec. I don't think that this conflicts with the semantics of importance, nor that a nesting of two `em`s emphasize within an emphasis, which I understand you were suggesting.

Comment: I think the HTML5 spec is just making more of a distinction between the two. In my interpretation, "emphasis" means stress in tone of voice. E.g., "You want to by *THOSE* jeans?" versus "You want to *BUY* those jeans?" have different meanings due to emphasis placement. OTOH, "Importance" doesn't have an effect based on placement. E.g., "**WARNING**: beware of dog!" would the same meaning if the importance were removed.

Comment: `<b> and <i> are both related to style` erm. Official HTML5 docs say otherwise. Citation needed?

Comment: @vaxquis linked above for HTML 4: `<b>` and `<i>` are font style elements, while `<em>` and `<strong>` are phrase elements. Any suggestions to improve this? For completeness, and also because your comment did not include a citation, in HTML 5.2, all these elements are described in [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content)

Comment: @Kariem HTML 4.01 is, well, a *bit* dated? HTML 5.2 doc (and earlier version too) say: "The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood", "The i element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text"; neither say anything about being related to *visual style* - both are described *semantically*. They even mention that visual style is not guaranteed!

Comment: @vaxquis please link your quotes, if you want to discuss this seriously. I do not understand in which way you (1) need a citation to obvious categorization in the linked specification and (2) after pointing out that this information is there you discuss the age of a specification linked in an answer written close to 11 years ago. What do you want to discuss? Would you like to suggest an edit? Is there anything I wrote not correct as per the linked specification?

Comment: @Kariem https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-b , https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-i - I just thought the links would be obvious to you. Yes, actually you could just enhance your answer to encompass HTML 5.x specs and mention the facts that the HTML spec changed significantly from 4.01, thus b and i being no longer visually stylistic.

Answer (score 7):

While `<strong>` and `<em>` are of course more semantically correct, there seem definite legitimate reasons to use the `<b>` and `<i>` tags for customer-written content.

In such content, words or phrases may be bolded or italicized and it is generally  not up to us to analyze the semantic reasoning for such bolding or italicizing.

Further, such content may refer to bolded and italicized words and phrases to convey a specific meaning.

An example would be an english exam question which instructs a student to replace the bolded word.

Comment: "more semantically correct"? What do you mean by that? Have you read the HTML5 spec on b/i tags?

Answer (score 7):

`<em>` and `<strong>` consume more bandwidth than `<i>` and `<b>`.

They also require more typing (if not auto-generated).

They also clutter the editor screen with more text. I seem to recall that programmers like smaller source files if they are the same. (And let's be real, they are the same. Yes, there are "technical" (<i>**cough**</i>, ahem, excuse me) differences, but that's mostly phony to begin with.)

With any of the above tags, you can use style sheets to customize how they appear to however you want if you need them to appear different than their defaults renderings.

Comment: Lol, this should be the accepted answer [(HHOS).](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/ha-ha-only-serious.html) Yours is the most down-to-earth and correct answer on this whole page, even if it's a bit of a joke. This whole thing about "semantics" is a silly game to begin with. We all know that anyone who looks up this question is here working with the major browser vendors in mind, Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. We just want to know what the *real*, *actual* differences might be, not what a committee debates about in its abundance of spare time.

Answer (score 5):

`<i>`, `<b>`, `<em>` and `<strong>` tags are traditionally representational. But they have been given ***new* semantic meaning** in **HTML5**.

`<i>` and `<b>` was used for font style in HTML4. `<i>` was used for italic and `<b>` for bold. In HTML5 `<i>` tag has new semantic meaning of '**alternate voice or mood**' and `<b>` tag has the meaning of **stylistically offset**.

Example uses of `<i>` tag are - taxonomic designation, technical term, idiomatic phrase from another language, transliteration, a thought, ship names in western texts. Such as -

```
<p><i>I hope this works</i>, he thought.</p>
```

Example uses of `<b>` tag are keywords in a document extract, product names in a review, actionable words in an interactive text driven software, article lead.

The following example paragraph is stylistically offset from the paragraphs that follow it.

```
<p><b class="lead">The event takes place this upcoming Saturday, and over 3,000 people have already registered.</b></p>
```

`<em>` and `<strong>` had the meaning of emphasis and strong emphasis in HTML4. But in HTML5 `<em>` means **stressed emphasis** and `<strong>` means **strong importance**.

In the following example there should be a linguistic change while reading the word **before** ...

```
<p>Make sure to sign up <em>before</em> the day of the event, September 16, 2016</p>
```

In the same example we can use the `<strong>` tag as follows ..

```
<p>Make sure to sign up <em>before</em> the day of the event, <strong>September 16, 2016</strong></p>
```

to give importance on the event date.

MDN Ref:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Answer (score 4):

**b** or **i** means you want the text to be rendered as bold or italics. **strong** or **em** means you want the text to be rendered in a way that the user understands as "important". The default is to render strong as bold and em as italics, but some other cultures might use a different mapping.

Like strings in a program, **b** and **i** would be "hard coded" while **strong** and **em** would be "localized".

Answer (score 2):

As others have said <b> and <i> are explicit (i.e. "make this text bold"), whereas <strong> and <em> are semantic (i.e. "this text should be emphasised").

In the context of a modern web-browser, it's difficult to see the difference (they both appear to produce the same result, right?), but think about screen readers for the visually impaired. If a screen-reader came across an <i> tag, it wouldn't know what to do. But if it comes across a <em> tag, it knows that whatever is within should be emphasised to the listener. And therein you get the practical difference.

Comment: `<b> and <i> are explicit (i.e. "make this text bold"),` erm. Official HTML5 docs say otherwise. Citation needed?

Comment: I posted this answer in November 2008. HTML5 was released in 2014. Are you honestly asking for me to cite in my answer a reference to something that came out eight years later??

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, the difference is that `<b>` and `<i>` hardcode font styles, whereas `<strong>` and `<em>` dictate semantic meaning, with the font style (or speaking browser intonation, or what-have-you) to be determined at the time the text is rendered (or spoken).

You can think of this as a difference between a “physical” font style and a “logical” style, if you will.  At some later time, you may wish to change the way `<strong>` and `<em>` text are displayed, say, by altering properties in a style sheet to add color and size changes, or even to use different font faces entirely.  If you've used “logical” markup instead of hardcoded “physical” markup, then you can simply change the display properties in one place each in your style sheet, and then ***all of the pages that reference that style sheet get changed automatically***, without ever having to edit them.

Pretty slick, huh?

This is also the rationale behind defining sub-styles (referenced using the `style=` property in text tags) for paragraphs, table cells, header text, captions, etc., and using `<div>` tags.  You can define physical representation for your logical styles in the style sheet, and the changes are automatically reflected in the web pages that reference that style sheet.  Want a different representation for source code?  Redefine the font, size, weight, spacing, etc. for your "code" style.

If you use XHTML, you can even define your own semantic tags, and your style sheet would do the conversions to physical font styles and layouts for you.

Comment: You can use style sheets to completely change the way that `<b>` and `<i>` are rendered too. Pretty slick, huh?

Comment: `b` and `i` don't hadcode anything. Just like any HMTL tag, they have a default CSS style and just like with any tag, you can change it to look the way you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I use both <strong> and <b>, actually, for exactly the reasons mentioned in this thread of responses. There are times when bold-facing some text simply *looks* better, but it isn't,  necessarily, semantically more important than the rest of the sentence. Here's an example from a page I'm working on right now:

"Retrieves <strong>all</strong> books about <b>lacrosse</b>."

In that sentence, the word "all" is very important, and "lacrosse" less so--I merely wanted it bold because it represents a search term, so I wanted some visual separation. If you're viewing the page with a screen reader, I really don't think it needs to go out of the way to emphasize the word "lacrosse".

I would tend to imagine that most web developers use one of the other, but both are fine--<b> is most definitely not deprecated, as some people have claimed. For me, it's just a fine line between visual appeal and meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Use them only if using CSS style classes is for any reason unconvinient or impossible (like blog systems, allow only some tags to use in posts and eventually embedded styles). Another reason is support for very old browsers (some mobile devices?) or primitive search engines (that give points for `<b>` or `<strong>` tags, instead of analysing CSS styles).

If you can define CSS styles, use them.

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` and `<i>`, having no actual semantic meaning (like @splattne pointed out) was true, *a long time* ago. In modern HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) they **do** have meaning. Check out the following links.

### Semantic meaning (from MDN)

- `<b>`: [Bring Attention To element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b)

  - Keywords in a summary
  - product names.

```html
<p>Here at company XYZ, we use <b>HTML</b> and <b>Javascript</b>.</p>
```

- `<i>`: [Idiomatic Text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)

  - Alternative voice or mood
  - Taxonomic designations (such as the genus and species "Homo sapiens")
  - Idiomatic terms from another language (such as "et cetera")
  - Technical terms

```html
<p>I <i>did</i> tell him, to arrive on time for the meeting.</p>
```

#### `<b>` vs. `<strong>`

It may help to realize that both are valid and semantic elements in HTML5 and that it's a coincidence that they both have the same default styling (boldface) in most browsers (although some older browsers actually underline `<strong>`). Each element is meant to be used in certain types of scenarios, and if you want to bold text for decoration, you should instead actually use the CSS font-weight property. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#%3Cb%3E_vs._%3Cstrong%3E)

#### `<i>` vs. `<em>`

The `<em>` element represents stress emphasis of its contents, while the `<i>` element represents text that is set off from the normal prose. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em)

### My 2 cents

I personaly prefer `<b>` and `<i>` over `<strong>` and `<em>`.

They are shorter, and their semantic meaning just *makes sense*, from a developer point of view too.
I have no idea if todays screen readers can work with them. If not, I think they will eventually. A18n is a difficult topic, I just follow the lead of documentation. MDN says I can use them, so I do.

Comment: False. The bold tag does in fact have semantic value. The idea that the b tag is not semantic is dated. Bold is an adjective that both means strong and also bold of style. That is also how it is used currently and in most of the web. Strong is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Difference between strong, b, bold, em, i?

Ans: These are inline properties.

Strong: It is used to show text bold or highlight it semantically.

Bold or b: This bold tag is just offset text conventionally styled in bold.

em: `<em>` tag semantically emphasizes the important word.

i : `<i>` tag just offset text conventionally styled in italic.

**note: you should use `<strong></strong>` and `<em></em>` tags their meaningful names which tell about the type of content. Semantic tags are also helpful for SEO.**

Answer (score 0):

`<b>` and `<i>` should be avoided because they describe the style of the text. Instead, use `<strong>` and `<em>` because that describes the semantics (the meaning) of the text.

As with all things in HTML, you should be thinking not about how you want it to *look*, but what you actually *mean*. Sure, it might just be bold and italics to you, but not to a screen reader.

Comment: Completely incorrect, <b> and <i> should not be avoided. They have semantic meanings in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

"They have the same effect. However, XHTML, a cleaner, newer version of HTML, recommends the use of the `<strong>` tag. Strong is better because it is easier to read - its meaning is clearer. Additionally, `<strong>` conveys a meaning - showing the text strongly - while `<b>` (for bold) conveys a method - bolding the text. With strong, your code still makes sense if you use CSS stylesheets to change what the methods of making the text strong is.

The same goes for the difference between `<i>` and `<em>` ".

Google dixit:

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_HTML_tags_b_and_strong

Answer (score 0):

You should generally try to avoid `<b>` and `<i>`. They were introduced for layouting the page (changing the way how it looks) in early HMTL versions prior to the creation of CSS, like the meanwhile removed `font` tag, and were mainly kept for backward compatibility and because some forums allow inline HTML and that's an easy way to change the look of text (like BBCode using `[i]`, you can use `<i>` and so on).

Since the creation of CSS, layouting is actually nothing that should be done in HTML anymore, that's why CSS has been created in the first place (HTML == Structure, CSS == Layout). These tags may as well vanish in the future, after all you can just use CSS and `span` tags to make text bold/italic if you need a "meaningless" font variation. HTML 5 still allows them but declares that marking text that way has *no meaning*.

`<em>` and `<strong>` on the other hand only says that something is "emphasized" or "strongly emphasized", it leaves it completely open to the browser how to render it. Most browsers will render `em` as italic and `strong` as bold as the standard suggests by default, but they are not forced to do that (they may use different colors, font sizes, fonts, whatever). You can use CSS to change the behavior the way you desire. You can make `em` bold if you like and `strong` bold and red, for example.

Comment: <b> and <i> are NOT deprecated in HTML 4, and are still fully supported even in the upcoming HTML 5.  <em> and <strong> are not replacements for them.  See also http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html

Comment: @thomasrutter They are still in HMTL5 but with a different meaning and with a very detailed explanation of how to use them or rather, how to not use them. Note that these tags have no meaning (bold and italic are not *meanings*, they are design instructions and HMTL is about meaning, CSS is aobut design) - HTML is about describing what a text is and not about how to render it (that was separated after HMTL3 for a good reason),.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Formatting Elements:**

HTML also defines special elements for defining text with a special meaning.
HTML uses elements like <b> and <i> for formatting output, like bold or italic text.

**HTML Bold and Strong Formatting:**

> The HTML <b> element defines bold text, without any extra importance.

```
<b>This text is bold</b>
```

> The HTML <strong> element defines strong text, with added semantic
>   "strong" importance.

```
<strong>This text is strong</strong>
```

**HTML Italic and Emphasized Formatting:**

> The HTML <i> element defines italic text, without any extra
>   importance.

```
<i>This text is italic</i>
```

> The HTML <em> element defines emphasized text, with added semantic
>   importance.

```
<em>This text is emphasized</em>
```

Comment: `The HTML <b> element defines bold text, without any extra importance.` `The HTML <i> element defines italic text, without any extra importance.` erm. Official HTML5 docs say otherwise. Citation needed?

Answer (score 0):

For  text  bold  using  `<b>`  tag

For  text  important  using  `<strong>`  tag

For  text  italic  style  using  `<i>`  tag

For   emphasized text using  `<em>`  tag

Answer (score 0):

First, **never use any of them if you want to style the text, to represent a design decision**. You should use CSS for that.

‍♂️ Don't do this

```html
<article>
  <h1>Illa videamus, quae a te de amicitia dicta sunt.</h1>
  <b>John Doe, 23 March 2023</b>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suam denique cuique naturam esse ad vivendum ducem. <mark>Venit ad extremum;</mark> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Quo igitur, inquit, modo?</a> Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. </p>

  <ul>
    <li>Quae fere omnia appellantur uno ingenii nomine, easque virtutes qui habent, ingeniosi vocantur.</li>
    <li>Transfer idem ad modestiam vel temperantiam, quae est moderatio cupiditatum rationi oboediens.</li>
    <li>Ergo in utroque exercebantur, eaque disciplina effecit tantam illorum utroque in genere dicendi copiam.</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

B doesn't stand for Bold anymore, I doesn't stand for Italic and U doesn't stand for underline. Do not think of these as your word processor buttons. The initials are left over from early Web standards. Nowadays, their meanings are:

- [`<b>`: The Bring Attention To element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b)
- [`<i>`: The Idiomatic Text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)
- [`<u>`: The Unarticulated Annotation (Underline) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u)

Funky names. They had to keep the initials somehow.

These elements *do* have a semantic meaning, albeit a weaker one, and are not deprecated. They are used to simply set apart some text from the surrounding text.

Getting back to the example:

This is semantic HTML

```css
cite {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal; /* we override the browser styling here, to make it look like the previous example */
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Illa videamus, quae a te de amicitia dicta sunt.</h1>
  <cite>John Doe, 23 March 2023</cite>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suam denique cuique naturam esse ad vivendum ducem. <mark>Venit ad extremum;</mark> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Quo igitur, inquit, modo?</a> Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. </p>

  <ul>
    <li>Quae fere omnia appellantur uno ingenii nomine, easque virtutes qui habent, ingeniosi vocantur.</li>
    <li>Transfer idem ad modestiam vel temperantiam, quae est moderatio cupiditatum rationi oboediens.</li>
    <li>Ergo in utroque exercebantur, eaque disciplina effecit tantam illorum utroque in genere dicendi copiam.</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

They produce the same *visual* result, but their semantics are different. Bolding the article information is a design decision. (also, the `<cite>` element is another semantic tag - it indicates the source of the content)

Additionally, these tags can be styled using CSS - look at the examples from MDN to see some potential styles.

The `<strong>` and `<b>` tags produce the same *visual* result by default in most browsers, but **this is just a coincidence**.

They have a different semantic meaning. While the `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>` tags simply set the text apart, the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags are used to create emphasis. This represents more than just setting some text apart, instead it marks it as **important**. For screen readers, it usually changes the tone as well. As you might suppose, the `<strong>` tag indicates a stronger level of emphasis.

- [`<em>`: The Emphasis element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em)
- [`<strong>`: The Strong Importance element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong)

Yes, I have totally seen `<strong>` to be styled as underlined in many places, which is totally valid, semantic HTML.

Finally, here are some examples to help you decide:

```css
.note {
  background-color: #ffff0080;
}
```

```html
<article>
  Humans (<i>Homo sapiens</i>) are the most widespread species of primate.<br>
  <i>Around the World in Eighty Days</i> was one of Jules Verne's most notable works.
  <div class="note">
    In these examples, I used the <code>&lt;i&gt;</code> tag to indicate text that should be simply set apart - you wouldn't intonate it when reading the above sentences aloud.
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  This is <em>urgent</em>. The deadline is in <em>one week</em>.<br>
  Linux Mint is <em>widely praised</em> for its user-friendly interface and stability.
  <div class="note">
    In these examples, I used the <code>&lt;em&gt;</code> tag instead, to indicate a text of particular importance.
  </div>
</article>
```

Of course, these examples also apply to `<b>` or `<strong>`.

Comment: B does in fact still stand for bold and it also carries semantic value because that is how it is used and has historically been used. To ignore the b tag as having semantic value is to invalidate 90% of the internet. The fact is that bold is also a semantic word. The knight was bold in his charge into battle. It is both descriptive of style and importance.

Comment: It stood for bold, in HTML3.

Answer (score -2):

`<strong>` and `<em>` are abstract (which is what people mean when they say it's semantic).
`<b>` and `<i>` are specific ways of making something "strong" or "emphasized"

Analogy:

Both `<strong>` is to `<b>` and `<em>` is to `<i>`

as

"vehicle" is to "jeep"

Comment: I don't see why this answer was downvoted. Many other answers with similar contents have been well received.

Answer (score -2):

In HTML Lang, these two tags are used as follows:

```
simple text this is test text normal text



simple text this is important textwith normal text
```

The major diversity between these two HTML tags is that bold makes text only visually look bold, while strong also symbolism hit the respective text as essential and indicates that it is a clear word or text section.

This difference is due to the fact that HTML code differentiates between symbolism and physical visual html tags. While the earlier refer to the meaning of the relevant areas, the latter merely define the optical display in browsers.

Answer (score -5):

We use the `<strong>` tag for text which has high priority for SEO purposes like product name, company name etc, while `<b>` simple makes it bold.

Similarly, we use `<em>` for text which has high priority for SEO, while `<i>` to make the text simply italic.

Comment: Some HTML tags really have SEO application.  Meta description, meta robot, or link canonical to name a few.  For as far as we know, strong/em is not one of these, neither in theory nor in practice.