# Finding the tag <strong> inside this div tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

My dom looks like:

```
<div class="blah">
  <a href=""><img .. ></a>
  <strong>blah blah</strong>
  <a href=""><img /></a>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of the strong when I know the class is "blah" ?

`$(".blah").find("strong")` doesn't work?

Comment: FYI.  The use of inline font styling, while not deprecated, is discouraged in the HTML spec.  A better way to handle this would be with a span with a CSS class assigned that styles the element the way you want.

Comment: the <strong> tag is not inline styling. the <b> tag however is. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
$(".blah").find("strong").html();
```

$(".blah").find("strong") will only return the jQuery object, not it's contents.

Answer (score 9):

```
var value = $('.blah strong').html();
```

Simpler than pim's answer but works in manly the same way. It finds all descendants of .blah that are strong tags and gives back the html content of the first one.

Comment: Except it has a typo: $('.blah strong').html();

Comment: I went for the original selector because the OP might be doing something to .blah before looking for the strong. Something like: $('.blah').doSomething().find('strong').html()

Comment: ..continued.. otherwise your selector is more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($(".blah > strong").text());
    });
</script>

    <div class="blah">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="#" /></a> <strong>blah blah</strong>
   </div>
```