# What is the difference between <cite>, <em>, and <i> tags of HTML?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between `<cite>, <em>, and <i>` tags of HTML ?

All render same default style in most of browsers.

Is there any meaning behind these tags ?

Can anyone give example about where these tags can be used ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`<cite>` is used for citations (either of resources or of their authors). They are commonly used together with `<q>` or `<blockquote>` (both used for quotations).

`<em>` means text emphasis (in a paragraph or some other text content).

In legacy HTML, `<i>` used to mean italicized text. In HTML5, `<i>` has been repurposed into [something else entirely](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element). (Note that this was not true at the time this answer was originally written.)

The only thing these three elements have in common is that all three of them are typically set in italics. In other words, the fact that they all have the same default style is mere coincidence.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers: `<i>` only says what the element *looks* like, which is of no use to e.g. blind people who browse your site using a screenreader. `<em>` and `<cite>` on the other hand tell you what they *are* and so, a screenreader can for example read an emphasized part in a louder, more forceful voice and leave a small pause before and after a citation.

But what the heck should it do with italics?

Comment: I don't know. Here's its description: "but in HTML5 you should use the <i> tag to define some part of a text as a certain type, not only how it renders in the layout." Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_i.asp

Answer (score 0):

`<cite>` is used when the content is some kind of articles.

`<em>` stands for "emphasis" is used to insists the meaning.

`<i>` stands for "italic", making the text italic.

cite & em is HTML 5 - standard, which insists in meaning. For a long time, old HTML (like `<i>`) is used for layout display. But the new standard requires that HTML should only consists of content, leaving layout works for css.

You may find some useful information about HTML 5 [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_phrase_elements.asp) and an interesting discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em).

Comment: Um, `<cite>` and `<em>` have been around since HTML 3.2 (that means more than 10 years ago). They're not new to HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually, I just know that in HTML 5 <i> is no longer valid.

Comment: `<i>` has, sadly, not been removed from HTML 5.