# Are there any differences between this 4 html elements?

Tags: italic

Can I clarify that these 4 elements below actually do the same job by rendering the text in italic and there is no difference in using each of them except to differentiate the type of content?

```
<i>
<em>
<address>
<cite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right, these 4 Elements basically renders all text or content as italic, the different off all these element just at the content.

- The `<i>` tag defines a part of text in an alternate voice or mood.
- The `<em>` tag is used to define emphasized text.
- The `<address>` tag defines the contact information for the author/owner of a document or an article.
- The `<cite>` tag defines the title of a creative work (e.g. a book, a poem, a song, a movie, a painting, a sculpture, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Do this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <i>italic text</i>
        <em>italic text</em>
        <address>italic text</address>
        <cite>italic text</cite>
    </body>
</html>
```

Put this into a file called `<filename>.html` and open it in a browser (e.g. Chrome). If the text looks the same, it looks the same!
[image]

As you can see, the `<i>` and `<em>` elements do not make a newline automatically, but otherwise there is no difference. If you'd like to change the styles yourself, you can create a css file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they all have the same default style which sets the content to italic.
And yes, a particular tag will be chosen according to the content.

Reference: For more information refer to below links:
[What is the difference between <cite>, <em>, and <i> tags of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537327/what-is-the-difference-between-cite-em-and-i-tags-of-html)
[What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)