# How to read text area value in CK-Editor rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor textarea:

```
 <textarea id='notification_message' name='notification[message]'>
```

I am just trying to read the value of ckeditor textarea via below code:

```
  var message = $("textarea[name='notification[message]']").val();
  alert(message);
```

But it give me blank value. How could I get the ckeditor textarea value?

Comment: You may be interested in the [The jQuery Adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery), using this you can use the `$('textarea.editor').val();` as normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the textarea value of a ckeditor textarea with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906085/getting-the-textarea-value-of-a-ckeditor-textarea-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['notification_message'].getData();
```