# Ck Editor does't take value while using jquery why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have create a form where I have define `ckeditor` which is work perfectly. Here I want to submit form value through `jQuery` but when I click on submit button it does't get `ckeditor` value on single click where other text field took its value on same click why `ckeditor` does't ? So, How can I fix this problem? Please help me.

code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      category = $("#category").val();
      temp_name = $("#temp_name").val(); 
      template_text = $("#template_text").val();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{"admin_id":admin_id, "category":category, "temp_name":temp_name, "template_text":template_text},
        url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>setting/add_template",
        success: function(data){
          $("#pro").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form method="post">
  <label for="name">Category<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="category" id="category" required="required" />

  <label for="email">Template Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="temp_name" id="temp_name" required="required" />

  <label for="email">Template Text<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <textarea class="ckeditor" name="template_text" id="template_text"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the textarea value of a ckeditor textarea with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906085/getting-the-textarea-value-of-a-ckeditor-textarea-with-javascript)

Comment: Thank You @Jerodev for reference it helps me.