# <tt> vs <code> elements when writing Java docs

Tags: java, html, javadoc

To represent `keywords` while writing  Java Docs  should I use the `<code>` element or the `<tt>` element? Are there specific situations when one should be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For inline code in Javadocs,you should use `{@code your-code-here}`

See [javadoc  - `{@code text}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@code%7D) for more details.

> Equivalent to `<code>{@literal text}</code>`.
>
> Displays *text* in `code` font without interpreting the text as HTML markup or nested javadoc tags. ..

Comment: On reflection, while having answered the question that was asked, this answers the question that *should* have been asked.  "How to represent code for the JavaDoc tool?"  For that, it would we worth a few more than the single up-vote it has got.  Great answer & thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 20):

From [the W3C on TT](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/tt).

> **HTML Reference**
>
> The  element is a non-standard element.
>
> HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature.
>
> **Examples**
>
> No, really, don't use it.

And I think that answers the question.  Choice of 2 elements, W3C says do not use one of them.

Comment: Weird that Java docs 7 still uses it e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Comment: @Pacerier I OTOH, am not the least bit surprised.  Sun/Oracle are not authorities on HTML.

Comment: Yes, yet `<tt>` seems to work on every single browser and has > 99.99% chance to continue to do so in the future *regardless* of what W3C says (while history has shown us that W3C isn't entire sure of where the future is going (starting with their xhtml nonsense) and their *future* recommendations often conflict with their previous ones (even for simple things like <b> and <i> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em#comment-8254050 ). So besides W3C's words, what are some *objective* reasons against using `<tt>`?

Comment: @Pacerier 1) Everything that can be achieved using that text can be achieved using the `<code>` tags. 2) The `code` element ***is*** part of an HTML standard. 3) 100% of User Agents claiming to conform to an HTML standard will support (and supposedly fix bugs related to the rendering of) the `code` element.  Would you use a deprecated Java method, or the one that replaces it? -- Now give me 3 'objective' reasons you might use this entirely redundant, non conforming element?

Comment: **1)** Not everything that can be achieved using `<tt>` can be achieved using `<code>`. The semantic meaning of `<tt>` is teletype fixed-width. The semantic meaning of [`<code>`](http://goo.gl/LI9JbT) is "code" (yea that "code" which relates to *programming* / *computers* etc). Now what if we want to indicate teletype fixed-width non-code words? It doesn't seem to be a good solution to hijack `<code>` to indicate teletype fixed-width words which are non-"code". Thus, we use `<tt>`. **2)** Your point 2 is a non-argument. Yea, it's part of an HTML standard, yet "part of a standard"...........

Comment: ...... *by itself* is not an objective reason; requires elaboration. **3)** So this seems to be your elaboration from point two. Allow me to repeat: `<tt>` works on 100% useragents and has > 99.99% chance to continue to do so in the future. Now, let me ask you a simple **question:** Is 100% of useragents more or less than 100% of conforming-useragents? **4)** Comparing "deprecated Java method" to `<tt>` is a stark example of [strawman fallacy](http://goo.gl/IpvQSF). `<tt>` has a 99.99% chance of future full-support. Does Java deprecated methods have a 99.99% chance of future full-support?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm done arguing about it.  If you want to use the `tt` notation, go right ahead.  Better still, enter your own answer on the benefits of `tt`.

Comment: This was never a debate, I'm merely seeking the **real** advantages/disadvantages of `<tt>` vs `<code>`. You know, not comments like W3C is cool, W3C is hot, they can't be wrong, whatever they say is right because I like them. Or comments like [W3C is authoritative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority), W3C is *big*, so whatever they say is right even if it's ["2+2=5"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHAuGA7gqFU).

Answer (score 7):

The code tag is preferred as tt is a font style element and as of HTML 4, styling by style sheets is preferred to font style elements.

Answer (score 3):

There is little practical difference between `code` and `tt`, i.e. software that processes HTML documents treats them the same way: they are by default treated as inline elements, rendered in a browser-dependent monospace font and possibly (depending on browser) in reduced font size. A distinction between them is mostly just theoretic talk. However, some automatic translation software makes a difference, treating `code` as having non-translatable content.

So there is some advantage in using `code`, but it is more important that you consider the real implications of either markup. If you don’t want reduced font size, set `font-size: 100%`. If you don’t want browser’s default monospace, which tends to be Courier New, set `font-family`.

Comment: seems great for javadoc code, I just discovered it looking at the Comparator.java source... it's littered with <tt> .. with <code> it would be much more verbose and harder to read... I really like it - and I guess if it's good enough for the javadoc sources, it's good enough for me)

Comment: @ycomp {@code List} is shorter than <tt>List</tt> and when you start adding special characters it is even more of a win: {@code List<String>} is more readable/maintainable than <tt>List&lt;string&gt;</tt>

Answer (score 0):

To provide more information about the subject:

In my case I added an [ASCII flow](https://asciiflow.com) in my class javadoc and I had to use this to keep a monospace rendering:

```
/**
 * <pre>{@code 
 * flow here
 * }</pre>
 */
```

I just verify it in my IDE popup. I guess it will work in an HTML page...