# Regular Expressions to bolden matches in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a function that matches an array of strings to a string of HTML code. It would then place a bold and /bold around the match. Now if I were matching the strings to regular text, the function would be something like:

```
function boldText(matches, text)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp(matches.join("|"),"g");
    text.replace(pattern,"<b>"+__what to write here?__+ "</b>"
}
```

However, since it's an HTML file, I don't want to bold anything that's between a less-than-sign and a greater-than-sign. Only stuff outside of HTML tags should be bolded. What might that regular expression be?

To reiterate, I'm looking for a regular expression that matches if-and-only-if the match isn't between a 'less-than-sign'+ any number of characters and any number of characters + a "greater-than-sign"

Ugh, nobody is answering me :(

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions!

Comment: @Tibos Is there some evidence that `<b>` tag deprecated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em

Comment: @VisioN thanks for pointing it out. It seems the meaning of `B` elements has changed (rather than deprecated the element): http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Comment: What's wrong with parsing HTML with regular expressions?

Comment: Isn't this besides the point? I'm trying to learn how to do this with regular expressions at least so I can understand regular expressions better. Please answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`$&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) pattern as follows:

```
text.replace(pattern, '<b>$&</b>');
```