# How do you create a hyperlink in a PHP file

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink, concatenation

I have an associative array in php. I am using a foreach loop and i want to create hyperlinks with the keys and values of my array like so:
go to http://www.microsoft.com to visit microsoft.

The hyperlink is the value and microsoft is the key.

Here is my code:

```
$software=array("microsoft"=>"http://www.microsoft.com",....);

foreach ($software as $key=>$item){
    echo "Go to ".<a href=$item></a>"." to visit " ."<b>".$key."</b><br>";
}
```

What is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: `"Go to <a href=\"".$item."\"></a> to visit <b>".$key."</b><br>"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You missed to quote the URL correctly
- Your a-tag had no content
- Your general quotation is invalid

So your code may look like this:

```
foreach ($software as $name => $url){
  echo 'Go to <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a> to visit <strong>'.$name.'</strong>';
}
```

And you probably do not want to use the b-tag, either use a styled span, or at least the strong-tag, see [What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)

Answer (score 0):

```
$software=array("microsoft"=>"http://www.microsoft.com",....);

foreach ($software as $key=>$item){

  echo "Go to <a href='".$item."'>to visit <b>".$key."</b></a><br>";
  // alternate
  // echo "Go to <a href='{$item}'>to visit <b>{$key}</b></a><br>";

}
```

Comment: Maybe because you use single quotes? Though they are allowed (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) it is not common practise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all your HTML is enclosed in quotes to make it a string. And then concatenate your variables in using the `.` operator.

```
$software=array("microsoft"=>"http://www.microsoft.com");

foreach ($software as $key=>$item){
    echo "Go to <a href=".$item.">".$item."</a> to visit <b>".$key."</b><br>";
}
```

Or you can include the variables in the string as long as you use double quotes and not single quotes. (Its a good idea to wrap the variable in curly braces to help the PHP parser know where the variable starts and stops).

```
$software=array("microsoft"=>"http://www.microsoft.com");

foreach ($software as $key=>$item){
    echo "Go to <a href={$item}>{$item}</a> to visit <b>{$key}</b><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please found your answer:

Replace the foreach loop with the below code

```
foreach ($software as $key=>$item){
   echo "Go to <a href=$item>$item</a> to visit <b>$key</b><br>";
}
```