# How do I make this text bold in HTML?

Tags: html

How do I make text bold in HTML? No CSS.

I want the word BOLD to be **BOLD**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: OP, look, I've bolded the word bold. Just right click on it and then inspect the element and you'll know how to do it.

Comment: This question creates a very `<strong>` impression that you have not studied the topic at all. This site is for substantive programming questions, not trivial questions that can be solved with two minutes of googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your have a syntax error in your HTML code, it should be:

```
<p>I want the word BOLD to be BOLD</p>
```

Then, there are two methods can make text display bold without CSS :

```
<p>I want the word <strong>BOLD</strong> to be <b>BOLD</b></p>
```

I recommend use strong element, because it's more semantic.

Look at the follow link, you will learn more:

[What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>I want the word<strong>BOLD</strong> to be <strong>BOLD.</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods, one of them is **HTML** solution.

```
</p>I want the word <b>BOLD</b> to be <b>BOLD</b><p>
```

Note the `<b>` element.