# Textview fromHtml bold tag not properly shown

Tags: android, html, textview

I am using fromHtml for some words, but it not properly shown.Sorry my bad english.

```
        Typeface tfArial = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arialtur.otf");

    String yazi="Deneme "+"<strong>"+"must be bold"+"</strong>"+" kayıt.";
    Spanned text1 = Html.fromHtml(yazi);
    TextView aa= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metin1);
    TextView ab= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metin2);

    aa.setText(text1);
    aa.setTypeface(tfArial);        
    ab.setText("Non arial font");
```

screenshot http://hizliresim.com/rd4gkV

Comment: Why is it "not properly shown" ? What is the actual problem ?

Comment: it seen italic, screenshot attached

Comment: are you sure your font supports bold?

Comment: Try Typeface TfArialBold = Typeface.create(tfArial, Typeface.BOLD);
and use 
aa.setTypeface(tfArialBold);

Comment: I have a regular font, bold font is must be in seperate file, or each file?

Comment: I changed font file, problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<strong>` HTML tag is not a "styling" tag. It's here only to indicates that the content is important. The default style of the `<strong>` relies on the web engine implementation.

You can have some information on these two links :

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp
- [What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)

Try to use `<b>` instead of `<strong>` if you want a bold text.

Comment: You have now to check your custom TypeFace if the "bold" version is correctly created.

Answer (score 15):

In case of `<b>` tag in resourses string you could wrap text in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`, i.e.:

```
<string name="textWithBold"><![CDATA[<b>BoldText</b>]]></string>
```

Then you could get and show it so:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.textWithBold)));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this several ways like

```
Typeface tfArial =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"arialtur.otf");
String yazi="Deneme <strong> must be bold </strong> kayıt.";
 // OR  String yazi="Deneme <b> must be bold </b> kayıt.";

TextView aa= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metin1);
TextView ab= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metin2);
aa.setText(Html.fromHtml(yazi));
aa.setTypeface(tfArial); 
 //OR  aa.setTypeface(tfArial,Typeface.BOLD);      
ab.setText("Non arial font");
```

Example :

using **strong** tag

Deneme  **must be bold**  kayıt.

using **b** tag

Deneme  **must be bold**  kayıt

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String message ="Deneme "+"<b>"+"must be bold"+"</b>"+" kayıt.";
aa.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));
```

You can also do same thing from XML by useing of  HTML tag