# Android: How to make the text size of Borderless button same as that of TextView

Tags: android, button, textview, text-size, borderless

In the following two images, there are four widgets in a horizontal linear layout:

1. A `TextView` with the text `Results:`
2. A `Borderless Button` with the text `My Cat`
3. A `View` which is a hack for a "Vertical Separator"
4. A `Borderless Button` with the text `My Dog`

Two questions:

1. `Results:` in the first one is bold because I used the `<b>` tag
   around it in the string resources file. But I used the `<strong>`
   tag in the second one, which does not make it bold.

   I [did read that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) `strong` has semantic meaning, so that may be a
   screen reader for blind people will read it in different tone, for
   blind people. **But visually, it should be bold, isn't it?**
2. I want the text in the `Button`s to be of the same size as the
   `TextView`. I believe for that I need to get the text size of the
   `TextView` (or the default size in the Android system? or "default
   size" is something on the user's device? :s ) in `sp` ([because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em) `sp`
   is also scaled by the user's font preference) **and then set the
   text size of the button same as that?  How can I do that**?

Can I do it in XML? or is it just possible programatically? and how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter Please let me know the reason??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use android:textStyle="bold" for bold text and android:textSize="12sp" for change text size of button in your xml.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Is `12sp` the default size of the text for `TextView`?

Comment: There are three "default" textSize values: 14sp,18sp,22sp
These are defined as the following TextAppearances
 - TextAppearance.Small
 - TextAppearance.Medium
 - TextAppearance.Large

Comment: Thank you again, but then what would be default TextAppearance? So that the sizes remain the same under all circumstances.

Comment: Default is 14sp. You can get default size by float size = new Button(this).getTextSize();

Comment: Thank you indeed, Can you append this information in the answer as well, will be useful for somebody visiting in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
Text size micro = 12sp.   
Text size small = 14sp.   
Text size medium = 18sp.   
Text size large = 22sp.
```