# Simulate em tag in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to eradicate my HTML code of tags such as `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<b>`, and `<em>`. I understand that `<strong>` and `<b>` can be accomplished in CSS by using `font-weight: bold`. I also understand that `<italic>` can be accomplished in CSS by using `font-weight: italic`. However, I am not sure how what the CSS equivalent for `<em>` is. After a lot of research, I really do not even see the difference between `<strong>`, `<b>`, and `<em>`.

Therefore, what is the difference between `<strong>`, `<b>`, and `<em>`, and what is the CSS equivalent of `<em>`? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In CSS, I guess you could use font-weight property!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em ...  Read the part *<i> vs. <em>* .... don't replace that tags are usefull for accessibility ... Visually em is just italic

Comment: I'm sure you have a very good reason to not use the semantic tags, but for anyone reading this afterwards – you should use semantically meaningful tags unless you have a *very good reason* not to.

Comment: Also, you could just inspect an `<em>` tag with the browser's dev tools and see what default styles are applied to it.

Comment: `<strong`> and `<em>` tell your browser to highlight the text in such away that makes it more apparent and striking, which 95% of the time means bold or italic, *however*, in some instances it does not. An example is for many Text-To-Speech programs. `<b>` means specifically bold - they will notice no difference, however `<strong>` and `<em>` may be expressed with certain inflection or emphasis. `<strong>` and `<em>` are *methods*, whereas `<b>` and `<i>` are specific styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `em` tag is a semantic tag for "emphasis" which most browsers render as `font-style: italic`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enbf09p7/)

---

> Most browsers will display the  element with the following default
>   values:

```
em { 
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Source: [HTML em tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp)

Answer (score 1):

basically, `<strong>` and `<em>` are SEO equivalents of `<b>` and `<i>` - by default they are styled the same, but the first ones give more *power* to the context

to answer your second question - you can style element as `<em>` by applying `font-style: italic`

Comment: This post really nails it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em