# HTML strong tag in navigation

Tags: contao

I noticed, that in the new Contao Template for Navigations the active page is declared by a strong tag.
Now in some Layouts you don't want the active page Name to be strong.
By Default Chrome and some other browsers declare strong as font-weight: bold.

What is better, to correct this by CSS or change the template to use a span tag?

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw. here is the GitHub discussion (in German): https://github.com/contao/core/issues/6336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `<strong>` is done for semantic reasons (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/271776/374996 for example). The "correct" way would be to account for this tag's default browser style with your own CSS (as usual). Otherwise you would lose the semantic meaning, if you simply convert it to `<span>`.