# the difference between <b> tag and <strong> tag

Tags: html

```html
<b>some paragraph</b>
<strong>some paragraph</strong>
```

I ask for the difference between this two tags.

Comment: Check this - https://codeengineered.com/blog/2013/html5-semantic-diff-bold-strong/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em

Answer (score 1):

The  bold tag is for "offset text conventionally styled in bold". If you read deeper into the details you'll see it adds, "without conveying any extra emphasis or importance".

strong is different. It "represents a span of text with strong importance." There is semantic meaning of importance here. In fact, a  tag within another  tag has even more importance.

explore here:
[What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em)