# Using <i> tags in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

I know that the following syntaxes work for `<em>` tags:

```
:emphasis:`lorum ipsum`
```

```
*lorum ipsum*
```

How can I generate `<i>` tags instead? I can't seem to find any mention in the  [Markup Specification](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html).

Comment: Sphinx or docutils (I don't know which) switched a few years ago from `<i>` to `<em>`, using similar reasoning to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2214933). That said, you could dig through the source code and find when that change was made and revert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Docutils version 0.17 (rsp. the repository version 0.17dev), the "html5" writer will write `<i>` tags, if a matching class value
is found in `inline` and `literal` elements::

```
.. role:: i

In the "html5" writer output,
:i:`this text is set in a <i> Element`.

This works also with other roles, 
if you give them the "i" class value, e.g.:

.. role:: alternative-voice
   :class: i, language-la

Lemonade consists primarily of :alternative-voice:`Citrus limon`.
```

Copy the example to a file "foo.txt", say
and call `rst2html5.py foo.txt foo.html` to see the result.

Comment: Could you clarify the relationship between the two code blocks? And which parts must be verbatim or user specified? It would also help if you provided three blocks: a short "before" sample, the transformation necessary for adding the <i> tag, and then a copy of the output.

Comment: The "code blocks" are rST ["role" directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles). They define two independent custom "interpreted text roles".

Answer (score 1):

Before we get into the guts of this, are you sure you really **need** `<i>` tags specifically?  People often use `<i>` when they really mean `<em>`...and they almost always look the same by default...

No?  You really need `<i>` tags>?  Okay, then here we go.

---

In order to control the HTML tags emitted by docutils, you need to create a new ["writer"](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html#writing-the-document).  These are the docutils components that generate output in whatever desired format (e.g. HTML, LateX, etc.).

You can find the various HTML writers included with docutils in the docutils source repo [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/docutils/writers/).

This will require writing some Python code.  Essentially up will need to provide a Python class which emits the HTML you want.

Looking briefly at the source, you can probably subclass whichever HTML writer best suits your needs (these days you probably want `html5_polyglot`) and override the `visit_emphasis` method.

You will then need to find a way to tell docutils to **use** your new writer.  Check out the [tools directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/tools/) for some examples.

If you're using Sphinx I'm really not sure off hand how to get a different writer in there.  You might have to modify (or monkeypatch) the Sphinx source.

Comment: Using a custom writer is straightforward with the [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/tools.html#generic-command-line-front-end) front-end available since Docutils 0.19.

Answer (score -1):

Text enclosed by single asterisk characters is emphasized:

This is *emphasized text*.
Emphasized text is typically displayed in italics.